# Use of ParallelDo with an iterative or recursive calculation

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, recursion, procedural-programming

Is it possible to use `ParallelDo` (or any similar parallelization method) to speed up the calculation of an iterative calculation, which takes a previous calculation result as input to new calculation?  It seems to me not possible conceptually, since each round will have to wait for the first to get its input, but I wonder if there are ways around this?

For example, if `f1[r]` is some predefined arbitrary continuous input function and `f2[r]` is some output function (over the `r` variable that runs from `0` to some number `a`, with some step called `step`, e.g. say `step=a/100`), then a calculation like this example

```
f1=1;
Do[
Do[
f2[r2]=NIntegrate[r1 f1[r1] BesselJ[0, r1 r2] E^(-I (r1^2 + r2^2)/2),{r1,0,a}],
(r2,0,a,step)];
f1=Interpolation[Table[{r2,f2[r2]},{r2,0,a,step}]],
{kk,100}]
```

would be difficult to speed up by parallelization (e.g. using `ParallelDo`), right?

Are there any suggestions to speed this up by parallel methods or other methods that are not to too difficult for a beginner in Mathematica to understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that can be parallelized here is the generation of the interpolation points. For example:

```
Clear[integrate, interpolate];
integrate[f_, r2_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
   r1 f[r1] BesselJ[0, r1 r2] E^(-I (r1^2 + r2^2)/2),
   {r1, 0, a}
];
interpolate[f_, a_?NumericQ, step_?NumericQ] := Interpolation[
  ParallelTable[
    {r2, integrate[f, r2, a]},
    {r2, 0, a, step}
  ]
];
```

Iterate the procedure twice, starting with a constant function:

```
results = NestList[
   interpolate[#, 1, 0.01] &,
   1 &,
   2
];
```

Plot the obtained functions at each iteration:

```
ReImPlot[Evaluate[Through[results[r2]]],
  {r2, 0, 1},
  PlotLegends -> Range[0, Length[results] - 1]
]
```

> [image]

## Edit

I don't think that with `NIntegrate` you can speed this up any further. The free parameter `r2` appears in the body of the integral, so I don't think that interpolation is going to help you too much here. You could make an interpolation over both `r1` and `r2` of which you then take the antiderivative over `r1`, but you also risk introducing numerical error that way. There's probably a reason why `NIntegrate` isn't faster here.

I do have another idea for speeding this up, though. We can use `ParametricNDSolveValue` to do the integration instead by re-phrasing the problem and considering `r2` to be a parameter. This should reduce the top-level overhead involved in calling `NIntegrate` multiple times. Here's how to do it:

```
Clear[integrate, interpolate];
integrate[f_, a_?NumericQ] := ParametricNDSolveValue[
   {y'[r1] == r1 f[r1] BesselJ[0, r1 r2] E^(-I (r1^2 + r2^2)/2), y[0] == 0},
   y[a],
   {r1, 0, a},
   {{r2, 0, a}}
];
interpolate[f_, a_?NumericQ, step_?NumericQ] := With[{
  int = integrate[f, a]
},
  Interpolation[
    ParallelTable[
      {r2, int[r2]},
      {r2, 0, a, step},
      Method -> "CoarsestGrained"
    ]
  ]
];
results = NestList[interpolate[#, 1, 0.01]&, 1&, 20];

ReImPlot[
  Evaluate[Through[results[r2]]],
  {r2, 0, 1},
  PlotLegends -> Range[0, Length[results] - 1], PlotRange -> All
]
```

This should be significantly faster than the method based on `NIntegrate`. You can also take a look at `FunctionInterpolation` to do the Interpolation step, since this might save you from having to sub-sample the integral more than you really need. For example:

```
int = Quiet @ FunctionInterpolation[
   integrate[1&, 1][r2],
   {r2, 0, 1}, 
   InterpolationPoints -> 50
]
ReImPlot[int[r2], {r2, 0, 1}]
```

`FunctionInterpolation` cannot be parallelized, though, so it's a trade-off

Comment: I appreciate your advice. My problem is that I find the loop I mentioned to be quite slow (especially as the functions evolve from iteration to iteration), so I suspected the culprit is the numerical integration, rather than the interpolation. Do you agree? (would your parallelizing of the interpolation points make much difference here?) How would you speed up such loop?  Would you use the anti-derivative techniques you mentioned in your other post instead of integrating?  (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225127/numerical-integration-over-experimental-numbers/225130#225130)

Comment: ... or will the primitive anti-derivative of the interpolation not help much in this case because the integration has a kernel made up of other functions (Bessel and r1)?  It would be nice if a method like that using anti-derivative of interpolation (without integration) could be used here. I think it would speed it up greatly when combines with your answer here, which basically paralellizes the loops over the variable `r2` but not the integration step itself.  Any advice on this?

Comment: Another question: isn't your answer fundamentally the same as parallelizing the inner Do loop in my original question (i.e. the Do loop over `r2` variable)? Or is your coding method faster?

Comment: @user135626 I updated the answer. I think you'll find it useful, but let me know. As for your last question: yes, it's sorta similar, but parallelizing assignments to variables is not the best way to do things because it has a lot of communication overhead. That's why `ParallelTable` is better here than `ParallelDo`.

Comment: This is a great answer. Really appreciate it! I just love the clarity of your treatment. May I finally ask: (1) I would like to be good in Mathematica and have the opportunity to enroll in any courses to master it more: do you recommend any particular courses? (2) Am I correct in that you used the `With` command in your answer to solve the paramteric ODE before the `r2` parameter values are assigned in `ParallelTable` as that would cause error in `ParametricNDSolveValue`? (3) But isn't `ParallelDo` also assigning different `r2` values to different kernels, just as `ParallelDo` would do here?

Comment: @user135626 (1) I'm not overly familiar with the courses, to be honest. A good online source to start with would be [Leonid's advanced intro](https://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/). Other than that: just reach out to Wolfram; I'm sure they would like to assist you find the right courses. (2) It's not to avoid errors, but purely for efficiency. The `With` ensures `ParametricNDSolveValue` evaluates only once, thus cutting down on redundant operations.

Comment: (3) If the assignment is done only in the parallel kernels, you can't create the interpolation in the master kernel because the definitions of `f2[r2]` do not exist in the master kernel. You can use `SetSharedVariables[f2]`, before the `ParallelDo`, but then each assignment will have to be transmitted to all other kernels (master and slave), causing communication overhead. In general, I recommend always using `ParallelTable` and `ParallelEvaluate` whenever you can. There aren't many situations where you need `ParallelDo` and you need a good understanding of the mechanisms involved to use it.