# How to integrate the interpolated data over the region in which it is non-zero?

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

Consider some toy-function which I then interpolate:

```
Function1[x_, y_] = If[4<x^3 + y^4 - x^2 < 5, Exp[-x^2 + y^2], 0];
DataInt = 
  Flatten[ParallelTable[{x, y, Function1[x, y]}, {x, 0, 100, 
     0.05}, {y, 0, 100, 0.05}], {2, 1}];
FunctionInt[x_, y_] = 
 Interpolation[DataInt, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x, y];
```

Note that there is a lot of points in which the interpolated function is zero. I want then to integrate this function:

```
NIntegrate[FunctionInt[x, y], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}]
```

The integral gives zero due to the fact that the domain in which FunctionInt is non-zero is very narrow. An brute-force way to improve this is to increase the integration accuracy. However, it may be more useful to define somehow the domain in which the function is non-zero, i.e. to get a function y = y[x] which defines this region.

Is it possible to do having the data?

Comment: Here's a quickish Riemann sum estimate: `SparseArray[Head[FunctionInt[x, y]]["ValuesOnGrid"]]["NonzeroValues"] // Total[#] 0.05^2 &` -- tends to overestimate the trapezoidal rule on a nonnegative function.

Comment: Do you know the symbolic description of the region such as `4<x^3 + y^4 - x^2 < 5` for your actual use case?  Do you know the formula for the data being interpolated such as `Exp[-x^2 + y^2]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 : I don't know the symbolic description and the formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Integrate` to accumulate an `InterpolatingFunction`:

```
Integrate[FunctionInt[x, y], x, y] /. {x -> 100, y -> 100}
(*  0.601376  *)
```

*Addendum:*

If the interpolation grid is regular as in the example (spacing = `0.05`), here's a quick way using a manual trapezoidal rule:

```
With[{fvals = Head[FunctionInt[x, y]]["ValuesOnGrid"]}, 
 Nest[Total[Most[#] + Rest[#]] 0.05/2 &, fvals, 2]
 ]
(*  0.601376  *)
```

A more general trapezoidal rule is implemented here:
[Choosing points of integration in NIntegrate (integrating a function given by a list without interpolation)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234832/choosing-points-of-integration-in-nintegrate-integrating-a-function-given-by-a/234897#234897)

Comment: The general trapezoidal rule refactored for this problem: `ifn = Head[FunctionInt[x, y]];
With[{fvals = ifn@"ValuesOnGrid"},
 Fold[Function[{y, dx}, dx . (Most[y] + Rest[y])/2], fvals, 
  Differences /@ ifn@"Coordinates"]
 ]`

Answer (score 3):

Find the domain over which the values are not zero:

```
minmaxes = MinMax /@ Transpose@Select[DataInt, #[[3]] != 0 &]

(* Out: {{0., 2.1}, {0., 1.5}, {0.0121552, 8.67114}} *)
```

Select a square region that includes that domain and interpolate over that:

```
squareint = 
  Interpolation[
     Select[DataInt, 0 <= #[[1]] <= 2.1 && 0 <= #[[2]] <= 1.5 &]
  ];
```

Integrate over that interpolated region numerically:

```
NIntegrate[
  squareint[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Rectangle @@ Transpose@squareint["Domain"]
]

(* Out:  0.554679 *)
```

Notice that you will get a `NIntegrate::slwcon` warning probably because of the perceived discontinuity over this domain.

This result compares well with the true value:

```
NIntegrate[
  Boole[4 < x^3 + y^4 - x^2 < 5] Exp[-x^2 + y^2],
  {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}
]

(* Out: 0.597656 *)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the OP's interpolating function will perform a linear extrapolation (`InterpolationOrder -> 1`) beyond the boundary.

Answer (score 3):

With the data:

```
Function1[x_, y_] = If[4 < x^3 + y^4 - x^2 < 5, Exp[-x^2 + y^2], 0];
DataInt = 
  Flatten[ParallelTable[{x, y, Function1[x, y]}, 
     {x, 0, 100, 0.05}, {y, 0, 100, 0.05}], {2, 1}];
FunctionInt[x_, y_] = Interpolation[DataInt, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x, y];
```

You could try:

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[{4 < x^3 + y^4 - x^2 < 5, 0 < x < 100, 0 < y < 100}, {x, y}];
Region@ir
```

[image: plot of the region where function is not zero]

```
NIntegrate[FunctionInt[x, y], {x, y} ∈ ir]
(*0.468457*)
```

However I get the warning message:

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

Something like this is not too surprising for a numerical integration routine and a discontinuous function.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) rather than [`If`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) for numeric functions

```
Function1[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{Exp[-x^2 + y^2], 4 < x^3 + y^4 - x^2 < 5}}];

int1 = NIntegrate[Function1[x, y], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}]

(* 0.597656 *)

reg = ImplicitRegion[
   4 < x^3 + y^4 - x^2 < 5 && 0 <= x <= 100 && 0 <= y <= 100, {x, y}];

int2 = NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2 + y^2], {x, y} \[Element] reg]

(* 0.597656 *)
```

The results are identical

```
int1 === int2

(* True *)
```

Comment: You don't seem to integrate an interpolating function? Or did I miss it? (The actual use-case may involved interpolation of data as indicated in the question, not a symbolic function.)