# Numerical integration of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration, numerics

I have a list, `p`, obtained by a complex numerical procedure. Its element has the structure: `{k,fi,z}`. Below I give a simplified version of this list containing 36 elements. Here the step of `k` is 1 and the step of `fi` is `2Pi/5`.  In real calculation, the steps will be much smaller, and the list - much larger. So, here is an example:

```
 p= {{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 1.25664, 0.}, {0., 2.51327, 0.}, {0., 3.76991,0.}, {0., 5.02655, 0.}, {0., 6.28319, 0.}, {1., 0., 58.927}, {1., 
  1.25664, 1.02628}, {1., 2.51327, 28.3293}, {1., 3.76991, 
  28.3293}, {1., 5.02655, 1.02628}, {1., 6.28319, 58.927}, {2., 0., 
  3.06756}, {2., 1.25664, 0.134298}, {2., 2.51327, 1.63558}, {2., 
  3.76991, 1.63558}, {2., 5.02655, 0.134298}, {2., 6.28319, 
  3.06756}, {3., 0., 0.579411}, {3., 1.25664, 0.0616836}, {3., 
  2.51327, 0.355197}, {3., 3.76991, 0.355197}, {3., 5.02655, 
  0.0616836}, {3., 6.28319, 0.579411}, {4., 0., 0.194156}, {4., 
  1.25664, 0.0308556}, {4., 2.51327, 0.130682}, {4., 3.76991, 
  0.130682}, {4., 5.02655, 0.0308556}, {4., 6.28319, 0.194156}, {5., 
  0., 0.0879579}, {5., 1.25664, 0.0171569}, {5., 2.51327, 
  0.0618171}, {5., 3.76991, 0.0618171}, {5., 5.02655, 0.0171569}, {5.,
   6.28319, 0.0879579}};
```

I need to integrate the function `z=z(k,fi)` over its arguments: from 0 to infinity over k and from 0 to 2Pi over fi.

What I have done so far is the following:

```
f = Interpolation[p, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
int = NIntegrate[
  f[k, fi], {fi, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {k, 0, 5}, 
  Method -> {"EvenOddSubdivision", Method -> "LocalAdaptive"}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 6]
```

This approach works. My question is if there is a better one.

**My question**: Is there a built-in or workaround method in Mma, so I can make this numerical integration without passing to the interpolation function?

In other words, is there a method that enables one to integrate the list p directly without further intermediate actions numerically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*On the data:*

The array `p` is given rounded to 6 sig. figs. (`PrintPrecision`), but the interval of integration for one of the variables is given as $[0,2\pi]$.  I changed the `Pi`-based dimension (2nd coordinate) to have complete 15.95-digit machine precision. I could have changed the `2 Pi`, which would have been easier; but I did it this way and didn't want to rework it.  The first coordinate is an integer and correctly rounded to machine precision; it needs no fixing. I could not fix the 3rd coordinate, so that will make the results below different those computed from the OP's actual data.

The fixed 2nd coordinate:

```
p = p /. (N@Round[#, 10^-5] -> # & /@ (2. Pi Range[5]/5));
```

*Several methods:*

For interpolating over a rectangular grid, `Integrate`/`InterpolatingFunction` has a built-in method for integrating, which I assume integrates the polynomial interpolants and gives the most accurate result (how to test that hypothesis though?):

```
Integrate[f[x, y], x, y] /. 
  Thread[{x, y} -> f["Domain"][[All, 2]]] // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.000202620849609375`, 156.39842883024124`}   *)
```

It is faster than the OP's method:

```
int = NIntegrate[f[k, fi], {fi, 0, 2 π}, {k, 0, 5}, 
   Method -> {"EvenOddSubdivision", Method -> "LocalAdaptive"}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 6] // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.0409303125`,         156.39869606089889`}    *)
```

Another built-in method is `Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"`", which is faster and gives the same answer as `Integrate`; it gives the exact same answer as the `Automatic` method but more slowly.

```
NIntegrate[f[k, fi], {fi, 0, 2 π}, {k, 0, 5}, 
  Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"] // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.00022087890625`,     156.39842883024124`}  *)

NIntegrate[f[k, fi], {fi, 0, 2 π}, {k, 0, 5}] // RepeatedTiming
(*  {{0.0005922978515625`,  156.39842883024124`}  *)
```

A manual implementation of `"InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` gives the same answer as `Integrate`, but much more slowly:

```
NIntegrate[
  f[k, fi],
  Evaluate[
   Sequence @@ MapThread[Prepend, {f@"Coordinates", {k, fi}}]]
  ] // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.0322208125`,         156.39842883024122`}  *)
```

*Remark:* `Integrate[f[x, y], x, y]` gives an interpolating function representing $\int_{y_1}^y \int_{x_1}^x f(x,y)\; dx\,dy$, which can be very useful.

---

**Addendum: Trapezoidal without `Interpolation[]`**

```
pp = Partition[p, 6];
fvals = pp[[All, All, 3]];
coords1 = pp[[All, 1, 1]];
coords2 = pp[[1, All, 2]];
Developer`PartitionMap[
  Mean@*Flatten, fvals,
  {2, 2}, {1, 1}
  ] . Differences@coords1 . Differences@coords2
(*  158.712  *)
```

Alternatively, for a uniformly spaced grid (as in the OP),
using `fvals` above:

```
wts = ConstantArray[1., Dimensions@fvals];
wts[[All, 1]] /= 2;
wts[[All, -1]] /= 2;
wts[[1]] /= 2;
wts[[-1]] /= 2;
Total[wts*fvals, 2]*
 (pp[[2, 1, 1]] - pp[[1, 1, 1]])*
 (pp[[1, 2, 2]] - pp[[1, 1, 2]])
(*  158.712  *)
```

**Addendum 2: Simpson's without `Interpolation[]`**

Need `Dimensions@fvals` to both be odd, or the last interval will be chopped off. Since the OP's `p` is a 6 x 6 array (of three coordinates), the following underestimates the integral. The grid also needs to be uniformly spaced.

```
Total[
  Developer`PartitionMap[
   # . {1, 4, 1} . {1, 4, 1}/36 &, fvals,
   {3, 3}, {2, 2}
   ],
  2] *
 (pp[[3, 1, 1]] - pp[[1, 1, 1]]) *
 (pp[[1, 3, 2]] - pp[[1, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: Thank you. do you think that one necessarily goes through the step of the interpolation?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Do you mean do you have to use `Interpolation[]` to get the result? Or are you asking about one of the methods, `Integrate[]` or `"InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` or some other? For the first question, I'd say it was easiest to use `Interpolation[]`, except maybe for a trapezoidal rule (weighted average of function values). But for the trapezoidal, you'd have to identify the edge and corner nodes of the domain, so there would still be some programming to do that `Interpolation[]` does for you.

Comment: If you're interested in the trapezoidal approach, [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234832/choosing-points-of-integration-in-nintegrate-integrating-a-function-given-by-a) shows several approaches. Sjoerd's answer in effect shows the `Integrate[]` approach using `Derivative[]` instead; in your case, it would be something like `prim = Derivative[-1, -1]@f;
prim[5, 2 Pi]`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I added a couple of methods that avoid `Interpolation` but make assumptions about `p`.

Answer (score 2):

I think we need to use `Interpolation` and it is recommend to use `InterpolationOrder -> 0`.

We compare with the two cases.

```
Clear[data];
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomReal[{-2, 1}, {10, 3}];
```

- **`InterpolationOrder -> 0`**

```
{ListPlot3D[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.8], 
   Filling -> Bottom, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All, 
   FillingStyle -> Cyan], 
  ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[8], White}]} //
  Show[#, Background -> Black, ViewPoint -> Top, 
   ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"] &
```

[image]

When we use `InterpolationOrder -> 0`, the domain will be subdivided by the [`VoronoiMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VoronoiMesh.html) method.

- **`InterpolationOrder -> 1`**

```
{ListPlot3D[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.8], 
   Filling -> Bottom, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All, 
   FillingStyle -> Cyan], 
  ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[8], White}]} //
  Show[#, Background -> Black, ViewPoint -> Top, 
   ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"] &
```

[image]

When we use `InterpolationOrder -> 1`, the domain will be subdivided by the [`DelaunayMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DelaunayMesh.html) method and construct a convex region which contain all the points and there are many point on the boundary.

Comment: I think the tensor-grid case and the unstructured grid case are different. One should take advantage of the additional structure in the OP's case.